# How do I read a full name that is separated by a comma from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I am trying to read full names that are separated by commas from a file that I ask the user to type in. In the example I will submit it is about the first ten presidents of the US. Here is my code (I have all the necessary libraries, I am just showing the main   function just so I can be told where I am mistaken):

```
 int main()
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_PRESIDENTS = 50;
    int n = 0;
    string president[NUMBER_OF_PRESIDENTS];

    string fileName;
    ifstream inputFile;

    cout << "Enter name of input file ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (inputFile.fail()) {
        cout << "This file does not exist.";
    }

    if (inputFile >> president[n]) {
        n++;
    }

    cout << n << " lines of text read from the input file.\n"
        << "Here are the unsorted names:\n"
        << "--------------------------- \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "[" << (i+1) << "] " << president[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The user inputs a txt file names "firstTen.txt" and the following txt is shown:

```
Washington, George
Adams, John
Jefferson, Thomas
Madison, James
Monroe, James
Adams, John Quincy
Jackson, Andrew
Van Buren, Martin
Harrison, William Henry
Tyler, John
```

My problem is that I want it to read each line and then go to the next president's name. However when it shows, it only shows up like this:
[image]

Comment: try using getline() function

Answer (score 1):

When reading from input file stream, you should read whole lines like this:

```cpp
if (getline(inputFile, president[n])) {
    n++;
}
```

instead of:

```cpp
if (inputFile >> president[n]) {
    n++;
}
```

For looping through all the names, you do something like this:

```cpp
int index = 0;
while (getline(inputFile, president[index])) {
    index++;
}
```

Please note that, since you are using `n` later for looping, you should use another variable for indexing.

Comment: This reads the full name. However it does not got to the next line for the next name. But thank you, one of the issues was solved!

Answer (score 1):

`inputFile >> president[n]` only reads up to the first whitespace character. `std::getline`, however, reads a whole line including any spaces.

You also need to loop through the lines in your input file so do this:

```
while (getline(inputFile, president[n])) {
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked by reading the full name, however it does not go to the next line and read the name on the next line. It did solve one of the issues I was having though.

Comment: @LLC Are you sure? I tested it and it works fine. Make you have saved the changes and rebuilt it. This the classic way of using `getline` to read a file's contents line by line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a logical error. I used an if statement instead of a while statement. Thank you for your help. It was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifstream` to read data from a file.

And to read line by line, you can do this:

```
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); )
{
    ...for each line in input...
}
```

Also you can do this

```
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
// your logic
}
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "more modern" C++ approach.

We want to read data about presidents. So, we create a tiny class "President", just containing the first and the last name. Because the class knows how to read and write its data, we will overwrite the inserter and the extractor operator.

And basically you want to read a csv file.

Still all people are linking to "How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?2 on SO. But, the questions is from 2009 and now over 10 years old. Most answers are also old and very complicated. So, maybe its time for a change.

In modern C++ you have algorithms that iterate over ranges. You will often see something like "someAlgoritm(container.begin(), container.end(), someLambda)". The idea is that we iterate over some similar elements.

In your case we iterate over tokens in your input string, and create substrings. This is called tokenizing. We do this to get the name and the first name from a file separated by comma.

And for exactly that purpose, we have the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And because we have something that has been defined for such purpose, we should use it.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence sregex. The begin part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a `std::regex` for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

- 1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
- -1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex.

So, now that we understand the iterator, we can copy the tokens from the iterator to our target, a `std::vector` of `std::string`. And since we do not know, how may columns we have, we will use the `std::vector`s range consturctor. Easy.

Next step. We want to read from a file. The file contains also some kind of same data. The same data are rows.

And as for above, we can iterate of similar data. If it is the file input or whatever. For this purpose C++ has the `std::istream_iterator`. This is a template and as a template parameter it gets the type of data that it should read and, as a constructor parameter it gets a reference to an input stream. It doesnt't matter, if the input stream is a `std::cin`, or a `std::ifstream` or a `std::istringstream`. The behaviour is identical for all kinds of streams.

And since we do not have files an SO, I use (in the below example) a `std::istringstream` to store the input csv file. But of course you can open a file, by defining a `std::ifstream sourceFile(filename)`. No problem.

And with `std::istream_iterator`, we iterate over the input and read similar data. In our case one problem is that we want to iterate over special data and not over some build in data type. For that we use the class President with the overwritten extratcor and inserter operators-

So we define a variable president and use its range constructor and give it a begin of a range and an end of a range. And, in our specific example, we use the begin and end iterator of `std::istream_iterator`.

If we combine all the above, reading the complete CSV file is a one-liner, it is the definition of a variable with calling its constructor.

Please see the resulting code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

const std::regex re(",");

std::istringstream sourceFile{R"(
Washington, George
Adams, John
Jefferson, Thomas
Madison, James
Monroe, James
Adams, John Quincy
Jackson, Andrew
Van Buren, Martin
Harrison, William Henry
Tyler, John)"};

struct President {
    // Data, at this moment: "name" and "firstName"
    std::string name{};
    std::string firstName{};

    // Overwrite extractor 
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, President& p) {

        // We will read one line
        std::string line{};
        if (getline(is, line)) {
            // Iterator to iterate over the comma separated field in the input string
            std::vector<std::string> data {std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1),std::sregex_token_iterator()};
            // Read name and first name. Easy to add more
            p.name = data[0]; 
            p.firstName = data[1];
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const President& p) {
        return os << p.firstName << " " << p.name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Read the complete source file into a std::vector
    std::vector<President> president {std::istream_iterator<President>(sourceFile),std::istream_iterator<President>()};

    // Show result on console
    std::copy(president.begin(), president.end(), std::ostream_iterator<President>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As much as I'd love to use a more "modern" approach, I am not allowed to used them. Since those come in later chapters. However, this code is very useful for me to use in the future. Thank you.